# Creating lines from polygon layers boundaries?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vectorization

I need to find boundaries between two polygon layers and express them as lines. There are plenty of polygons in each layer, so I'd like to avoid doing it "by hand".

Example:

[image]

Red line shows how boundaries should look.

Comment: As it stands I think your question is too broad.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  I always look for the single question mark that indicates the actual question, and in your "question" there is not one.

Comment: There is blues lines, pink lines and I see one red line. Please refine  your question. However, I think I guess what you're up to, if you're more precise we might be able to guide you. Have a try with Integrate tool (**Beware to be in an edit session before trying Integrate** !! ) + buffer/merge polygon and layers methodology, and/or cleaning your layer(s). The best would be first to have a clean polygon layer, then after, you can start to think of lines.

Comment: You now have a question mark in your title, which is good, but that should only summarize the question in your question body.  Can you try to put a single one in there too, please?

Comment: @PolyGeo The first sentence is quite obviously a question, even though it's not explicit, it's not that hard to change mentally "I need to" into "How to".

Comment: @BartoszKP That first sentence is stating a requirement. It is not asking a question.  You are free to guess what is being asked but I usually prefer a question to be clear before I attempt an answer. In this case the ambiguity is not so much the lack of a question mark but getting that would be a starting point to finding the remaining details that I think are necessary to answer what I am guessing may be what is being asked.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm not guessing anything. Perhaps it would be easier for the OP if you stated what "remaining details that you think are necessary" in particular are missing.

Comment: "The fact that vectorization wasn't very precise and there are sometimes gaps between polygons is another difficulty".  How did you create these two polygon layers?  What do these gaps look like close up? What have you tried in order to eliminate those gaps from your workflow?

Comment: I've simplified the question so now I guess it is more useful.  Gaps between my polygons are another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done directly with the "polygon to line" toolbut you need an advanced licen in order to use it. However, you need to handle the lack of precision (e.g. using integrate on a copy of your dataset).

Alternatively, you could isolate the green and the orange polygons in two layers and compute their intsection with line outputs (define a tolerance in the tools parameter to account for the lack of precision).

Answer (score 0):

This might help. "How To: Convert shapefile polygons to polylines"
http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000004861